# A parametric model for inverse of quadratic equation

Tags: optimization, regression, parametric, parameter-estimation, least-squares

I have data $\left\{ q_i, p_i \right\}_{i = 1}^{N}$ from a model $p_i = a q_i^2 + b q_i + c$:

[image]

I know data is always in the positive quadrant as $q_i \geq 0, \, p_i \geq 0$ and I also know $a > 0$ (Smiling parabola).

I am after a **parameteric model** for $q_i = g_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} (p_i)$:

[image]

Polynomial regression doesn't work well here as it requires high degree.
I wonder if there are known parametric models, preferably linear, for such data.
I'd guess it is something with `sqrt` yet I am not familiar with parametric family built on it.

**Remark**
I am looking for a parametric model, to be estimates using *linear least squares* / *nonlinear least squares*. I am not after solving for each point the quadratic equation.

Comment: Would switching the (in)dependent variables with one another $(x,y)\to(y,x)$ work?

Comment: @TymaGaidash, Anything that I can optimize its parameters will work.

Comment: The inverse function is $q_i=\frac{1}{2a}\left(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-p_i)}\right)$. Use a non-linear regression software to the fitting ( computation of $a,b,c$ ).